# linked list implement in python

Tags: python, singly-linked-list

```
class Node:

    def __init__(self,data):
        self.data=data
        self.next=None

class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head=None

    def printlist(self):
        pointer=self.head
        while pointer is not None:
            print(pointer.data)
            pointer = pointer.next

l=LinkedList() l.head=Node("Mon")

List item

n2=Node('Tue') n3=Node('Wed')

#linking first node to second l.head.next = n2 n2.next = n3 l.printlist()


# my doubt is how can self.head access data and next from different class
```

Comment: Python has no concept of `public` vs `private` if that's what you are asking about, so one class can see all the attributes of another class

Answer (score 1):

```
class Node:

    def __init__(self,data):
        self.data=data
        self.next=None

class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head=None

    def printlist(self):
        pointer=self.head
        while pointer is not None:
            print(pointer.data)
            pointer = pointer.next

l=LinkedList() 
l.head=Node("Mon")
l.head.next=Node('Tue') 
l.head.next.next=Node('Wed')
l.printlist()
```

We can store object of different class in head , we have not any restriction on it in python.

in this code, **l.head=Node("Mon")** where Node("Mon") is object of class Node which we are storing in l.head.